# Array values vanishing after completion of ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a very odd situation with Angular 7.  I am populating an array using an asynchronous call in ngOnInit and although I confirm the array is populated after the call, when I attempt to use it later it is empty.

Is there something with the lifecycle of ngOnInit that would cause the array to be erased?

My config is:

```
    Angular CLI: 7.1.4
    Node: 11.3.0
    OS: darwin x64
    Angular: 7.1.4
    ... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
    ... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
    ... router

    Package                           Version
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    @angular-devkit/architect         0.11.4
    @angular-devkit/build-angular     0.11.4
    @angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.11.4
    @angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.11.4
    @angular-devkit/core              7.1.4
    @angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.4
    @angular/cdk                      7.2.0
    @angular/material                 7.2.0
    @ngtools/webpack                  7.1.4
    @schematics/angular               7.1.4
    @schematics/update                0.11.4
    rxjs                              6.3.3
    typescript                        3.1.6
    webpack                           4.23.1
```

Code is as follows (I've removed all error handling calls to simplify the code and can confirm that no errors are thrown):

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

    import { CurrencyWindow } from './currency-transaction-window';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })

    export class AppComponent {

      baseURL = 'http://localhost/api/'; 

      currencyTransactionWindows: CurrencyWindow[];  
      constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {  }

      setRootCurrency( ) : void {

        if ( !!this.currencyTransactionWindows ) {

          // do something

        } else {

          console.log("Something wrong - we lost our transaction windows!");

        }

      }

      determineAvailableCurrencies( transactionWindows: CurrencyWindow[]) {

        this.currencyTransactionWindows = transactionWindows;

        if (!this.currencyTransactionWindows ) {
          console.log("Failed to get currency transactions");
        } else {
          console.log( this.currencyTransactionWindows.length + " currency transaction windows found ");
        }

      }

      getCurrencyTransactionWindows( ): Observable<CurrencyWindow[]> {

        return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}/select.php`).pipe(
          map((res) => { return res['data']; }) ); 

      }

      ngOnInit() {

        this.getCurrencyTransactionWindows( )
          .subscribe( this.determineAvailableCurrencies );

      }

    }
```

The class for the imported data is:

```
    export class CurrencyWindow {
        constructor(
            public currencySource: string,
            public currencyTarget: string,
            public firstDate: Date,
            public lastDate: Date
        ) {}
    }
```

HTML for app-root is:

```
<button (click)="setRootCurrency()">Click me!</button>
```

Console output is:

```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
app.component.ts:43 15 currency transaction windows found
app.component.ts:30 Something wrong - we lost our transaction windows!
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try this: `ngOnInit() {

        this.getCurrencyTransactionWindows( )
          .subscribe( res => { this.determineAvailableCurrencies(res); });

      }`

Comment: "!!this.currencyTransactionWindows" is this condition correct? with double not operator?

Comment: You can do what @JacopoSciampi said, or `.subscribe(this.determineAvailableCurrencies.bind(this));` to keep `this` scope to the component instead of the subscribe callback.

Comment: `determineAvailableCurrencies` is a function that require a parameter. I just guessed that is the response from the `getCurrencyTransactionWindows`subscription. Hopefully I'm right, and that's why you are not getting the right logic to work.

Comment: No, what OP said will still pass `res` to the function. But inside the function `this` will not be `AppComponent` it will be something like `SafeSubscriber` which obviously doesn't have `currencyTransactionWindows` which will be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    this.getCurrencyTransactionWindows( )
      .subscribe( this.determineAvailableCurrencies.bind(this) );
```

or this

```
    this.getCurrencyTransactionWindows( )
      .subscribe( data=>this.determineAvailableCurrencies(data) );
```

IMHO data is never bound to component field.

Comment: @EdwardCaulfield please accept the answer if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar odd behaviour once, where it turned out that Chrome was submitting the form when I clicked on the button.

The fix in that case was adding a type="button" to the html, so in your case:

```
<button type="button" (click)="setRootCurrency()">Click me!</button>
```